# Vuejs router link to sub component

Tags: vue.js, components, router

Currently I have my router set up to link to page components. Each of these page components have sub components so for example.

**Home**

```
<slider></slider>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<panel></panel>
```

Say I wanted to link to the Home page components  component is this possible.

So the route would be http://example.com/home/panel

The above is just an example but is ideally what I am looking for. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nested routes](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/nested-routes.html) by defining the routes children:

```
const routes = [{
  path: '/home',
  component: Home,
  children: [{
    path: 'panel',
    component: Panel
  }]
}]
```

Then in your `Home` component you would place a `router-view` tag to serve up the component:

```
<router-view></router-view>
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/craig_h_411/srxafk39/